# Shift baseline of text in table (For HTML email signature)

Tags: html, css, typography

Okay so I would like to move some of my text lower in a table that is going to get sent through email.  I can accomplish this using  CSS: `position: relative; top: .35em;` but this doesnt seem to work in gmail, outlook, or thunderbird.  Is there an alternative way to do this?  I messed around with margins and padding, but to no avail...  Here is a fiddle of where I am stuck: http://jsfiddle.net/z9t2memx/
Essentially I would like the line with TEST PERSON: MR. TEST to be about 5-10px lower. How cn I acheve this in a way that will work in most email clients?

Comment: add empty `td` with spacer above

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/z9t2memx/2/)

Comment: You could also add `padding-top:10px` to your `table` styles...it would keep everything in proportion within the cells, too.

Comment: Adding padding unfortunately also moves the log which I would like to leave centered.  Adding and empty space works, except that it renders invisible in Microsoft outlook, despited having a background color property, and a defined height and with.